# Angular: how to prevent removal of child route's path from url when clicking on the already-selected parent

Tags: angular, routes, ng-bootstrap

I'm using, in part:

```
"@angular/core": "10.2.3",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
```

The problem: With a set of top-level "parent" tabs and second tier "child" tabs (ngbNav), clicking on the original parent tab *after* clicking on a child tab, removes the child's path from the url.

The need: if I click the parent tab, then click a child tab, then click the *same* parent tab as before, I don't want the child's path to be removed from the url.

Example of current behavior:

- click "Jobs" parent tab, the url becomes "/jobs"
- click "Filter" child tab, the url becomes "/jobs/filter"
- click "Jobs" parent tab again, the url becomes "/jobs" again

...but I want the url to stay "/jobs/filter" (and the corresponding active Filter tab to remain visible).  In other words, when the 3rd click happens nothing should change.  I'm hoping to accomplish this with router configuration rather than some sort of javascript solution that prevents the click.

This is how my routes are configured:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'jobs',
    component: JobsComponent,
    canActivate: [RouteAccess],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'filter',
        component: JobsFilterComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'summary',
        component: JobsSummaryComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here's the HTML if it's needed:

```
<div class="top-level-tabs">
  <!-- one of the parent tabs -->
  <a class="nav-link" 
     [routerLink]="['/jobs']" 
     [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}">JOBS</a>
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
<nav ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs" id="second-tab-set">
  <ng-container ngbNavItem>
    <a ngbNavLink class="tab-height-large" [routerLink]="['/jobs/filter']">Filter</a>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container ngbNavItem>
    <a ngbNavLink class="tab-height-large" [routerLink]="['/jobs/summary']">Summary</a>
  </ng-container>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same approach as Ionic Framework did for the router link. The Ionic sources are in the [router-link-delegate.ts file](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/5.5.x/angular/src/directives/navigation/router-link-delegate.ts). Sorry, I don't have time to provide the full solution. It would look like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
})
export class RouterLinkDelegate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    @Optional() private routerLink?: RouterLink,
  ) {
  }

  /**
   * @internal
   */
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(ev: UIEvent) {
    if (this.routerLink.routerLink.startsWith(this.router.url)) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

You might need to work on the logic for checking if you want to prevent the default click handler.
After the code is finished, you just need to add RouterLinkDelegate into the declarations array of the modules which should use this logic.